# when seekbar is zero then set mute icon,seekbar is high from zero then set unmute icon

Tags: android, icons, seekbar

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJhw.png]

just change the icon of mute and unmute when seekbar goes to zero mute,while seekbar higher from zero set unmute.how to do programmatically

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **[SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)**

> **SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener**
>
> A callback that notifies clients when the progress level has been changed. This includes changes that were initiated by the user through a touch gesture or arrow key/trackball as well as changes that were initiated programmatically.

**sample code**

```
SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.YourseekBar);     
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        if(progress==0){
         // perform your ACTION here
        }else{
           // perform your ACTION here
        }


    }       
});
```